# Can you subscribe to an event/webhook for an alert trigger on SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, alert

As someone with no experience with `SharePoint Online`, I am looking for a way to trigger some custom code whenever an `alert` is triggered. I've been looking at `remove event receivers`, `webhooks` etc., but I'm having a hard time figuring out what is the best way, and what is possible using `SharePoint Online` specifically.

Say a document was updated and an alert was triggered, then rather than the alert simply resulting in an email being sent out, I would then like my custom code to be triggered to do an action. And note that I still want the 'Alert Me' functionality to be the trigger.

Is there a perhaps way of doing so in SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you could use the Remote Event Receivers.

Then to trigger “Alert Me”, you could configure the alert when existing items are modified.

And in the remote event receiver, you could add the custom action when the document is updated.

More references:

[Create remote event receiver SharePoint Online Step by Step Tutorial.](https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/create-remote-event-receiver-sharepoint-online/)

[Steps to create a Remote event receiver using visual studio 2015 for SharePoint Online and deploy into Microsoft Azure.](https://www.sptechcon.com/blog/steps-to-create-a-remote-event-receiver-using-visual-studio-2015-for-sharepoint-online-and-deploy-into-microsoft-azure)